# Designing copper fill zones in Kicad 7

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, copper-pour

I have the upper layer of the board as GND.
I want to have the bottom layer of the board as VCC (of course, I have declared the VCC label in the schematic).

When I select the copper fill zones, this is what I see:

[image]

Both the upper and the bottom layer have a default selection of `<no_net>`, even when I explicitly set the net as GND or VCC. When I reopen the Copper Fill Zones tool, the preselected is the `<no_net>`.

I know that my upper layer is indeed GND, because I can easily spot it. For example:
[image]

However, how can I be sure that the bottom layer is indeed VCC?
(BTW, here appear two more internal layers that I did not create them and I do not want them, but this is another story)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is set to no-net. If you want to see nets that are set to VCC or GND select the appropriate tick-box. To get rid of the extra inner layers go to the physical stackup page and select 2 copper layers: -

[image]

Your setup is set to 4 copper layers thus: -

[image]

I'm using KiCAD V7 btw.

Comment: For some reason, copper fill zones do not work for me. I updated from Kicad 5 to Kicad 7. Even the upper side GND zone is impossible to do now.

Comment: You are doing something wrong that I cannot help with given the information you have provided. Yet, you show an image of a copper fill in your question so, I am at a loss.

Comment: I fixed it. There were remnants of many copper zones. Thus for the frontside copper, there were existing many copper zones. Perhaps from the Kicad update, i don't know.